# How to remove ListView's Adapter

Tags: android, header, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, illegalstateexception

In My application I'm using a ListView.
During running, I have to change the list's header.
I'm trying to do that in the following code -

```
                    if (mGroupMembersList != null) {
                    mGroupMembersList = null;
                    MTListView tempListView = (MTListView) this.findViewById(R.id.groupMembersList);                                
                    tempListView.addHeaderView(getHeaderView(headerTitle));                 
                    tempListView.setAdapter(groupMembersAdapter);
                    mGroupMembersList = tempListView;
                }
```

But when it gets to

```
tempListView.addHeaderView(getHeaderView(headerTitle));
```

it throws

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot add header view to list -- setAdapter has already been called.
```

How it can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided your full code,can't tell you how to fix your existing code.
Here is how I implemented header in List View

```
  //add header to list
    ListView lv = getListView();
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header, (ViewGroup)     
    findViewById(R.id.header_layout_root));
    lv.addHeaderView(header, null, false);

    //add some list items
    String listItems[] = {"List Item One", "List Item Two", "List Item Three", "List  
                           Item Four", "List Item Five"};
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                                   listItems));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer to my problem.
Here is my solution -

```
                    String headerTitle = groupsVector.get(activeGroupIndex - 1).name + " "
                        + getString(R.string.view_group_members);

                if (mGroupMembersList.getHeaderViewsCount() == 0) {
                    mGroupMembersHeaderView = getHeaderView(headerTitle);
                    mGroupMembersList.addHeaderView(mGroupMembersHeaderView);
                }

                if (mGroupMembersList != null) {
                    TextView titleTextView = (TextView) mGroupMembersHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                    titleTextView.setText(headerTitle);                 
                    mGroupMembersList.setAdapter(groupMembersAdapter);
                }
```

Thanks,
Eyal.